# Unable to Receive ACTION_NEW_PICTURE on Samsung and HTC UI's

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, action, intentfilter

I have an app which has a broadcast receiver receiving the action ACTION_NEW_PICTURE. This receiver works fine on most devices except the ones with the htc and samsung camera UI's.

Here's my receiver:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Log.e(TAG, "Intent Received");
            // Toast.makeText(Helper.this, "Intent Received",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (intent.getAction() == android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE) {
                NameEditor.mediaType = "image";
            } else {
                if (intent.getAction() == android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_VIDEO) {
                    NameEditor.mediaType = "video";
                }
            }
 NameEditor.pictureUri = intent.getData();
            startActivity(dIntent);
        }
    };

    filter = new IntentFilter(android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE);
    filter.addAction(android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_VIDEO);
    try {
        filter.addDataType("image/*");
        filter.addDataType("video/*");
    } catch (MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, that broadcast is new to API Level 14, so unless the devices in question are running Android 4.0, that broadcast is not expected.

Second, AFAIK, there is no requirement that a camera app has to send that broadcast, whether that camera app is provided by a device manufacturer or a third party off the Play Store. Certainly, I could write a camera app that would not send that broadcast. Hence, I would consider `ACTION_NEW_PICTURE` to be something your app should use opportunistically, but not rely upon.

Comment: Thanks, but then what should I do to support older devices and other camera apps?

Comment: @user1641724: Since you have not explained what you are trying to accomplish, that is impossible to answer. There is no general purpose, always-guaranteed way for you to spy on what the user does with the camera.

Comment: Well I want to carry out an action once the user takes a photo (not delete one).

Comment: @user1641724: You can try to use a `ContentObserver` on `MediaStore`, but you have no way of restricting it to new camera images -- new images from any source would trigger your logic. Or, you can try using a `FileObserver` on the external public storage directory for photos (see `Environment`). However, camera apps do not have to store their photos there. It is not possible for you to reliably find out when "the user takes a photo".

Comment: Oh ok I figured it out myself, thanks for your help. You just have to keep a few checks on the returned uri.

Comment: @TanujNayak can you please provide some more details on how you were able to do it finally ?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have a question about this intent: since there are so many camera apps (both of manufacturers and third party), what exactly ensures that the intent will be fired by those apps?

Comment: @CommonsWare i've searched for such a problem, and i've found one person complaining to samsung that it doesn't honor this guideline: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=247557&listLines=15&orderBy=8&startId=zzzzz~&startPage=3&curPage=5 . according to what he wrote, the CDD says the camera app "MUST" broadcast the intent... i wonder what's going on, and what can be done to listen to new images being created/taken... maybe there is no other way and you must have a contentObserver of some kind...

Comment: @CommonsWare i've even tried using an intent receiver of MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED and ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE , but those just don't get called...

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I would expect that broadcasts aren't tested as part of the Compatibility Test Suite. Moreover, bear in mind that there are countless third-party camera apps, none of which have *any* requirement to broadcast anything in particular. "maybe there is no other way and you must have a contentObserver of some kind" -- there is no requirement for any camera app to do anything involving a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's too bad, but i guess they can't force third party apps to do so... about contentObserver , i was talking about contentObserver on the MediaStore - the same files that the gallery apps show. maybe on this one: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "i was talking about contentObserver on the MediaStore" -- there is no requirement for a camera app to store its images in a place that is indexed by the `MediaStore`.

Comment: @CommonsWare usually, when you take a photo, it should also be available on the gallery app, so that you could share it with other people. i think this assumption is good enough for most cases. anyway, about the CTS, it's very weird that google didn't add this test. it's like a bug on their test cases. is there a way to report this to them?